# If I'd like my question marked as duplicate, should I flag for mod attention?

Tags: support

I have a question that I asked here:

> [What happens after you leave Windows 7 inactivated?](https://superuser.com/questions/652372/what-happens-after-you-leave-windows-7-inactivated)

and it is a duplicate of [Windows 7 activation period](https://superuser.com/questions/108949/windows-7-activation-period).

I've flagged it as a duplicate as well, but:

If I agree that it is a duplicate, and given that I can't delete it (as there are already answers), should I flag it for moderator attention, stating that it's a duplicate? Is this what I should do in the future?

Or should I just leave it flagged as duplicate?

Comment: Do a combination of both. Delete your question but improve the existing question with your screenshots. Your question is actually better then the existing question.

Comment: @Ramhound Unfortunately, I can't delete a question that has existing answers, but I'll flag it both ways.

Comment: You are of course correct.  If you make a small modification to your post I will remove my downvote.  Didn't realize how poor existing question was before it was to late :-$

Comment: @Ramhound Done and done. I also added my screenshots to the existing question.

Comment: Upvoted your question as promised.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ramhound suggests, I would do a combination of both.  Since the flag for dupe will go to the masses (review queue), and the mod flag will be viewable to the mods.

However, before flagging (and when you get 'nuf rep here soon, vote to close) compare the two questions and see which on is of a higher quality.  There have been cases, where I will actually vote to close the older post when it's of a lower quality and has crap answers, versus the most recent.

Comment: Thanks. If I were to do the latter part, wouldn't I be removing the reputation from the higher scoring answers on the older question, though?

Comment: @Moses No.  Closing a question doesn't remove rep.  It simply stops from more answers being given.